# Recurrence relations with master theorem: polynomial function

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

let `T(n)` be an increasing function

```
T(n) = aT(n/b)+f(n)
```

where `a >= 1` and `b >= 2`

To use `Master theorem`, one of the conditions which must be satisfied is that `f(n)` should be a polynomial function.

In this example, it is clearly not

`T(n) = 2T(n/4) + n^(1/2) + 42` .

The book counts `f(n)=n^(1/2)` as a polynomial function but what I am taught is that if `f(n) = n^a` is a polynomial function, then `a` must be a natural number. Is there a special condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might call this a generalised polynomial, but it is what is intended. Many theorems that work for 'natural number' polynomials also work for these generalised polynomials. Just think of differentiating or integrating.